# Akka Streams & Http. External Http Request in version 1.0-RC4

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

This code doesnt seem to work anymore when attempting to create an http client/flow:

```
lazy val myConnectionFlow = 
 Http().outgoingConnection("localhost", port).flow

def myRequest(request: HttpRequest): Future[HttpResponse] = 
 Source.single(request).via(myConnectionFlow).runWith(Sink.head)
```

It seems the `flow` method is no longer available. Has it indeed been deprecated? Is the following now the preferred way to create Http Connections?

```
 val connFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] =
  Http().outgoingConnection("localhost", port)

 val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
  Source.single(HttpRequest(uri="XXX"))
  .via(connFlow).runWith(Sink.head)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is no deprecation period for experimental modules, in particular not before reaching 1.0.